# Changing <li> css automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Slider that start automatically. I want that when a certain image appear, the right subject in .menu-li will become font-weight:bold. If i'm not clear enough, there is a good example here: http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls -> only here the slider is not working automatically with setInterval.

```
    var autoSlider = "";
    var startRefresh = function() {
    if (autoSlider !== "") {
        return;
    }

    autoSlider = setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(300)
        .promise().done(function() {
            $('#slideshow > div:first').next()
            .fadeIn(300)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        });

    },  5000);
};
startRefresh();
```

HTML:

```
            <ul class="menu-ul">
                <li class="menu-li a">travel</li>
                <li class="menu-li b">sport</li>
                <li class="menu-li c">real estate</li>
                <li class="menu-li d">hotels</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: maybe check like this `$("id of img element").attr('src') === 'img1_on.jpg'` then do this if condition is true `$('.menu-li').css('text-weight','bold');`

Comment: Hey, I don't want to be a css grammar nazi, but the property is 'font-weight', not 'text-weight'.

Comment: @harrypujols You are right my bad:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve any variable data in an HTML element with jQuery's `.data('name')`. To create intial values with HTML, use the `data-whateveryouwant=""`. Then when you have your two elements, you can retrieve that data value and set the current link to be bolded.

**Slider's HTML with `data-` attributes:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div data-menutarget=".menu-ul li.a"></div>
    <div data-menutarget=".menu-ul li.b"></div>
    <div data-menutarget=".menu-ul li.c"></div>
</div>
```

**New `setInterval` Function**

```
var first = $('#slideshow > div:first');
first.fadeOut(300)
.promise().done(function() {
    var second = first.next();
    second.fadeIn(300);
    first.appendTo('#slideshow');
    $(second.data('menutarget')).css('font-weight','bold');
    $(first.data('menutarget')).css('font-weight','normal');
});
```

Comment: well, the slider is still working, but there is no change in the li font-weight. and also, i need those classes :) any reason why you deleted them?

Comment: @yuvalsab Those classes were just a simple way to let you style whatever selected menu item (you would just need to create the CSS). I changed it to `.css` to only bold/unbold the selected item.

Comment: with or without the classes, i still couldn't make it work. any idea why?

Comment: This might work, but starting any attribute with a dot `.` seems like bad practice to me and might not be supported in all browsers/doctypes. You'd be better of by leaving out the dot, and inserting it in jQuery manually, like so: `$("."+second.data("menutarget"))`.

Comment: eventually the problem was somewhere else in the script. now it's working :) thanks!